# Wordpress ajax success response

Tags: ajax, wp-mail

I'm trying to create a contact form in Wordpress using wp_mail and ajax

The emial works but I'm having problems with the ajax success reponse.

After the email is sent I need to show the user a message that the email was sent.

The js to validate the form and show the succes message.

```
    $atj(function(){
      $atj('#training-submit').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        if(verfiyFields()) {
            alert('here');
            requestData = {
              'action' : 'myajax-submit',
              'firstName' : $atj("#name").val(), 
              'email' : $atj("#email").val(), 
          }
          $atj.post(MyAjax.ajaxurl, requestData).done(function(result){        
            result = jQuery.parseJSON( result );
            console.log(result);
            if(result == 'success'){
              $atj('.training-form [type=text]').val('');
              $atj('.training-form-message').append('<p class="training-form-complete-message">Thank you for the  email</p>');
            }
          });
        }
      });
    })



    //Verfiy 
    function verfiyTrainingFields() {
      var flag = true;

      var name =        $atj('#name');
      var email =       $atj('#email');

      if(name.val().indexOf(' ') === -1 ){
        name.parent().prepend('<p class="form-error">Please enter name, first space last</p>');
        errorMessage($atj('.form-error'));
        flag = false;
      }
      if(!IsEmail(email.val())){
        email.parent().prepend('<p class="form-error">Please enter valid email address</p>');
        errorMessage($atj('.form-error'));
        flag = false;
      }
      return flag;
    }
```

The functions.php file to send the email and send the ajax reponse.

```
    function myajax_submit() {

        $name = sanitize_text_field($_POST['firstName']);
        $email = sanitize_text_field($_POST['email']);

        $headers[] = 'From: ' . $name . ' <' . $email . '>' . "\r\n";
        $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html' . "\r\n"; //Enables HTML ContentType. Remove it for Plain Text Messages

        $to = 'me@mysite.co.uk';

        $message = 'Name: ' . $name . "\r\n" . 'email: ' . $email;

        add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' );
        wp_mail( $to, 'Email Test', $message );
        remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' ); 

        echo 'email sent';

        // generate the response
        $response = json_encode( array( 'success') );

        // response output
        header( "Content-Type: application/json" );
        echo $response;

        exit;
    }
```

The email is sent and the 'email sent' echo fires but the if(result == 'success'){ in the js doesn't work.

The console.log(result) in the js file gives the following.

```
    <br />
    <b>Warning</b>:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'set_html_content_type' not found or invalid function name in <b>/Users/user.name/Desktop/MAMP-DocRoot/appname/src/php/wp-includes/plugin.php</b> on line <b>192</b><br />
    email sent<br />
    <b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/user.name/Desktop/MAMP-DocRoot/appname/src/php/wp-includes/plugin.php:192) in <b>/Users/user.name/Desktop/MAMP-DocRoot/appname/src/php/wp-content/themes/sitename/functions.php</b> on line <b>66</b><br />
    ["success"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use 2 echos for an ajax response.

Try this:

js:

```
  $atj.post(MyAjax.ajaxurl, requestData).done(function(result){        
    console.log(result);
    if(result == 'success'){
      $atj('.training-form [type=text]').val('');
      $atj('.training-form-message').append('<p class="training-form-complete-message">Thank you for the  email</p>');
    }
  });
```

php

```
function myajax_submit() {
// snip...

 $mail_check = wp_mail( $to, 'Email Test', $message );
 remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' ); 

 if( $mail_check) 
   echo 'success';
 else
   echo 'failure';
 exit;
}
```

Comment: I see that user51442 has a history of not following up on Answers with questions or acceptance.

Comment: shanebp - I do follow up on answers with questions and accepting but I still can't get it to work. Your answer might be correct but I can't get it to work so I can't accept it. i can't accept it because I have less then 15 reputations